# Update config map object from service app

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have my microservice and ConfigMap deployed in cluster.

I have a need to update the value of variable defined in `ConfigMap` object on the fly. I can re-start the microservice programmatically (like re-create the service pod). The main thing is to keep the `ConfigMap` object in the cluster and only update the value in it.

My current idea is to define env variables in an external file:

```
key1: foo
key2: bar
```

and in ConfigMap manifest mount the file:

```
spec:
  containers:
    image: ...
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /clusters-config
      name: config-volume
  volumes:
    - configMap:
        name: my-env-file
      name: config-volume
```

I wonder if using this approach, what is the main pitfalls/cons I should consider?

Is there an better option/solution if not using the volume mounted `ConfigMap` but keep variables inside ConfigMap manifest?

Comment: what do you mean by keeping config map in cluster and update value ? you can update configmap and restart the pod or configmap get also auto-updated if you are mounting to POD. could you please little describe more i didn't get proper scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> The main thing is to keep the ConfigMap object in the cluster and only
> update the value in it.

As said in the comment proper requirement is not clear to me still trying my best to answer.

**Yes**, you can keep the **configmap** object in the cluster and update the value in it.

The **mount** option would be the best one to use instead of using **Env** as per your requirement.

If you mount the **configmap** to **Deployment** of POD after some **TTL** **second** it got **auto-updated** to the deployment or inside POD.

So if you are mounting the configmap there might be delay little bit but it will get **auto updated** in pod.

In this scenario, your application should be smart which takes new values out of the **mounted file** once updated.

You can refer to my article on auto update the configmap for more details : https://faun.pub/update-configmap-without-restarting-pod-56801dce3388

**Example**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
  hello: world
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: configmaptestapp
        image: <Image>
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config
          name: data-volume
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: data-volume
          configMap:
            name: test-config
```

now anytime you want to update the configmap just apply YAML with the updated value, the POD value will get updated **automatically** **without restart**.

If you are using as **Env** you have to restart the POD each time once configmap is updated.

To automate this you can also leverage the **Reloader** which will restart your deployment if configmap got updated. https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Comment: if the requirement is not clear, perhaps you could wait for clarification before answering.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the suggestion, just thought to try my best to answer and scratch my head a little and written the answer, instead of leaving the question unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

**4 ways** that you can use a `ConfigMap` to configure a container inside a Pod:

1. Inside a container command and args
2. Environment variables for a container
3. Add a file in read-only volume, for the application to read
4. Write code to run inside the Pod that uses the Kubernetes API to read a ConfigMap

===========================================================

You choose the **3rd way**. As to your questions:

> I wonder if using this approach, what is the main pitfalls/cons I should consider?

One possible pitfall: When a `ConfigMap` currently consumed in a volume is updated, projected keys are eventually updated as well. This means that your **external file containing the variables will be eventually updated in the container**. However, the total delay varies for different kubelet configuration, which may affect application supporting hot reloading(reloading the config file on the fly). *If you always re-create new pods after modifying the `ConfigMap`, the pitfall does not exist.*

> Is there an better option/solution if not using the volume mounted ConfigMap but keep variables inside ConfigMap manifest?

Yes, use the **1st or 2nd approach**, like the example below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: game-demo
data:
  # property-like keys; each key maps to a simple value
  key1: "foo"
  key2: "bar"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-demo-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: demo
    image: alpine
    command: ["sleep", "3600"]
    env:
    # Define the environment variable
    - name: ENV_KEY1  # Notice that the case is different here
                      # from the key name in the ConfigMap.
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: game-demo  # The ConfigMap this value comes from.
          key: key1  # The key to fetch.
    - name: ENV_KEY2
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: game-demo
          key: key2
```

**Note**: ConfigMaps consumed as environment variables are not updated automatically and require a pod restart.